# Search Controller not shown up

Tags: swift

I walked through Ray Wenderlich tutorial on how to implement search controller to table view, and my problem is that the search bar is not showing up.
I already searched for this problem and none of the solutions fixed that.
Here is my code:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Friends"
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
```

[Seach Bar not displayed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12uzG.png)

Comment: you need to scroll from top to bottom and you can able to view search control

Comment: Already checked that and still the search bar isn't showed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

use this let in class ViewController. instead of ur code use this code

```
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```